# Set-theoretic definition of natural numbers (von Neumann ordinals)

Tags: scheme

I need program this function, but I don't know how..

This function `von-neumann` is recursive, where

*`zero`* is defined as *`empty set`*, number

*`one`*  is defined as *`the set that contains the empty set`* and

*`N`* is defined as *`the union of the set N-1 and the set that contains N-1`*.

A full definition is found [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-theoretic_definition_of_natural_numbers).

Example of use:

```
> (von-neumann 0)
()
> (von-neumann 1)
(())
> (von-neumann 2)
(() (()))
> (von-neumann 3)
(() (()) (() (())))
> (von-neumann 4)
(() (()) (() (())) (() (()) (() (()))))
```

I have this..

```
(define von-neumann
  (lambda (n)
    (cond [(= n 0) '()]
          [(= n 1) '(())]
          [else (append '(() (())) 111 ) ])))
```

Comment: This is not a precise enough error description for us to help you. *What* doesn't work? *How* doesn't it work? What trouble do you have with your code? Do you get an error message? What is the error message? Is the result you are getting not the result you are expecting? What result do you expect and why, what is the result you are getting and how do the two differ? Is the behavior you are observing not the desired behavior? What is the desired behavior and why, what is the observed behavior, and in what way do they differ?

Comment: I got this task, but I don't know how to write it.
My code is only the beginning of this task. Unfortunately I don't know how to continue.

Answer (score 1):

This is referring to the https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-theoretic_definition_of_natural_numbers

Your attempted code is very good, almost done but you have a mistake on this line:

```
         [else (append '(() (())) 111 ) ])))
```

what you need to do instead is append the set version of n-1 with a set containing the set version of n-1. Like this

```
         [else (append (von-neumann (- n 1)) (list (von-neumann (- n 1))))]
```

Answer (score 1):

What you need to do is like this:

```
(define von-neumann
  (lambda (n)
    (if (zero? n)
        '()
        (let ((n-1 (von-neumann (- n 1))))
          (append n-1 (list n-1))))))


1 ]=> (for-each
 (lambda (n)
   (newline)
   (display n)
   (display (length n)))
 (map von-neumann (iota 5 0 1)))
()0
(())1
(() (()))2
(() (()) (() (())))3
(() (()) (() (())) (() (()) (() (()))))4
;Unspecified return value
```

I tested it with `mit-scheme`.  I used the definition found in wikipedia at the entry  [set-theoretic definition of natural numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-theoretic_definition_of_natural_numbers) (also known as *[von Neumann ordinals](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ordinal_number#Von_Neumann_definition_of_ordinals)*).

Note also that instead of `(append n-1 (list n-1))` one can use simply `(cons n-1 n-1)`, but in this case the sets will be reversed -- `4 = ((((()) ()) (()) ()) ((()) ()) (()) ())`.